# Sending Byte Array in kafka .Net

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api, confluent-platform

I am currently facing a problem with my code below which I have written for Kafka. The code is quite simple, the Producer produces a byte array and the consumer wants to consume the array. The problem with it is that it neither displays any error, nor I am able to get the required output. I am sure that the byteArray(Size: 4.06MB) input is getting the proper values to be passed on to the kafka pipeline. Both the Consumer methods are not giving the required output. In Method 1 the code doesn't passes the IF condition of "Consumer.Consume()" and in method 2 the "msg" variable is coming null. Please advise as to what I am doing wrong.

```
    Kafka Producer:
        public class BookingProducer : IBookingProducer
            {
                public void Produce(byte[] byteArray)
                {
                    var config = new Dictionary<string, object>
                    {
                        { "bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092"},
                        { "message.max.bytes", "5242880"}
                    };

                    using (var producer = new Producer<Null, byte[]>(config, null, new ByteArraySerializer()))
                    {
                        var result = producer.ProduceAsync("timemanagement_booking", null, byteArray).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                        //Console.WriteLine($"Value: {result.Value}");
                        producer.Flush(10000);
                    }
                }
            }

    Kafka Consumer Method 1:
    public class BookingConsumer
        {
            public void Listen()
            {
                var config = new Dictionary<string, object>
                {
                    { "group.id","booking_consumer" },
                    { "bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092" },
                    { "enable.auto.commit", "false" },
                    { "fetch.message.max.bytes", "5242880" }
                };

                using (var consumer = new Consumer<Null, byte[]>(config, null, new ByteArrayDeserializer()))
                {
                    consumer.Subscribe("timemanagement_booking");

                    while (true)
                    {
                        Message<Null, byte[]> msg;
                        consumer.Poll(10000);
                        if (consumer.Consume(out msg, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)))
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(msg.Value.ToArray());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
Kafka Consumer Method 2:
public class BookingConsumer
    {
        public void Listen()
        {
            var config = new Dictionary<string, object>
            {
                { "group.id","booking_consumer" },
                { "bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092" },
                { "enable.auto.commit", "false" },
                { "fetch.message.max.bytes", "5242880" }
            };

            using (var consumer = new Consumer<Null, byte[]>(config, null, new ByteArrayDeserializer()))
            {
                consumer.Subscribe("timemanagement_booking");
                consumer.OnMessage += (_, msg) =>
                {
                    if (msg != null)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(msg.Value.ToArray());
                    }
                };
                while (true)
                {
                    consumer.Poll(10000);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: After searching for a bit, I came to know that the broker pipeline supports only 1.5MB of byte array size whereas I was trying to send an array of 4 MB and that was the problem. I reduced the resolution of the file and it worked. Hope it helps others also...